# what is best way to get select options, values from js array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to write js so that my select option dropdown gets the value and text from my array. js is new for me. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sloga/9BkSS/)

I need the value to be the number and text the text in quotes from:

```
var locations = [
    [23, 'Main Room'],
    [1, 'Main Lobby'],
    [2, 'Training Room'],
    [56, 'Main Office'],
    [57, 'Lower Office'],
    [9, 'Lower Lobby'],
    [62, 'Conference Room'],
    [22, 'Outdoor Patio'],
    [63, 'Upper Lobby']
    ];

var select = document.getElementById("selectRoom");
for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var opt = locations[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt; // I just want the text within quotes from 
    el.value = opt; // I just want the number from opt
    select.appendChild(el);
}
```

or should my array look like?
locations = { "23": "Main Room", "1": "Main Lobby" };

Comment: shortcut: new Option("key", "value");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix, change to:

```
el.textContent = opt[1]; // I just want the text within quotes from 
el.value = opt[0]; // I just want the number from opt
```

However, like you are thinking, it is more common to use an object for this:

```
var locations = {
    23: 'Main Room',
    1: 'Main Lobby',
    2: 'Training Room',
    56: 'Main Office',
    57: 'Lower Office',
    9: 'Lower Lobby',
    62: 'Conference Room',
    22: 'Outdoor Patio',
    63: 'Upper Lobby'
    };

var select = document.getElementById("selectRoom");
for(var key in locations) {
    if(location.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = locations[key]; // I just want the text within quotes from 
        el.value = key; // I just want the number from opt
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using the quick fix instead of object but I think it will come in handy. On another note, do you know how I could put the array/object into an extjs scrollable menu?

Answer (score 3):

Your locations are arrays with two elements, your value is in index 0 and your text in index 1

```
for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var opt = locations[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt[1]; 
    el.value = opt[0];
    select.appendChild(el);
}
```

I you want to use an object instead, which is preferable, then setup your locations as @Hallvar suggests, I was going to edit with his same answer but he beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from the array you'll have to use `locations[i][0]` and `locations[i][1]` for the text

Also you can use the Option constructor to minimize your code

```
for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var el = new Option(locations[i][1], locations[i][0]);
    select.appendChild(el);
    //select.add(el, null); I think there is an issue with add in IE
}
```